# Is there a simpler javascript code for executing onclick function for multiple buttons that has the same code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below:

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("week_dropdown-button");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
    });
  }
  
  function w1e1() {
    document.getElementById('w1e1').style.backgroundColor="black";
    document.getElementById('w1e1').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    w1e1 = document.getElementById('w1e1');
    sessionStorage.setItem('W1E1', w1e1);
  }
  function w1e2() {
    document.getElementById('w1e2').style.backgroundColor="black";
    document.getElementById('w1e2').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    w1e2 = document.getElementById('w1e2');
    sessionStorage.setItem('W1E2', w1e2);
  }
  function w1e3() {
    document.getElementById('w1e3').style.backgroundColor="black";
    document.getElementById('w1e3').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    w1e3 = document.getElementById('w1e3');
    sessionStorage.setItem('W1E3', w1e3);
  }
  function w1e4() {
    document.getElementById('w1e4').style.backgroundColor="black";
    document.getElementById('w1e4').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    w1e4 = document.getElementById('w1e4');
    sessionStorage.setItem('W1E4', w1e4);
  }
  function w1e5() {
    document.getElementById('w1e5').style.backgroundColor="black";
    document.getElementById('w1e5').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    w1e5 = document.getElementById('w1e5');
    sessionStorage.setItem('W1E5', w1e5);
  }
  function w1e6() {
    document.getElementById('w1e6').style.backgroundColor="black";
    document.getElementById('w1e6').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    w1e6 = document.getElementById('w1e6');
    sessionStorage.setItem('W1E6', w1e6);
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('W1E1')) {
      document.getElementById('w1e1').style.backgroundColor="black";
      document.getElementById('w1e1').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    }
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('W1E2')) {
      document.getElementById('w1e2').style.backgroundColor="black";
      document.getElementById('w1e2').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    }
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('W1E3')) {
      document.getElementById('w1e3').style.backgroundColor="black";
      document.getElementById('w1e3').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    }
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('W1E4')) {
      document.getElementById('w1e4').style.backgroundColor="black";
      document.getElementById('w1e4').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    }
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('W1E5')) {
      document.getElementById('w1e5').style.backgroundColor="black";
      document.getElementById('w1e5').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    }
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('W1E6')) {
      document.getElementById('w1e6').style.backgroundColor="black";
      document.getElementById('w1e6').style.border="solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    }
  }
```

```css
.week_dropdown-button{
  padding: 0.2em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px outset darkgrey;
  background-color: rgb(75,75,75);
  width: 11.1em;
}
.week_dropdown-button:hover{
  background: darkgrey;
  border: inset rgb(75,75,75);
}
.button:hover{
  background: darkgrey;
}
.week_dropdown-container{
  height: max-content;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 12.5em;
}
.week_content-button{
  background: rgb(75,75,75);
  
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%; /* lebarnya terhadap week_dropdown-container */
  text-align: center;
}
.button{
  background-color: rgb(75,75,75);
  border: solid 1px black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 0;
}
a, a:hover, a:visited{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.active{
  background: darkgrey;
  color: black;
  border: inset rgb(75,75,75);
}
```

```html
<button class="week_dropdown-button">WEEK 1</button>
<div class="week_dropdown-container">
  <div class="week_content-button">
    <button id="w1e1" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1e1()"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 1 (EP.001/156)</a></button>
    <button id="w1e2" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1e2()"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 2 (EP.002/156)</a></button>
    <button id="w1e3" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1e3()"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 3 (EP.003/156)</a></button>
    <button id="w1e4" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1e4()"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 4 (EP.004/156)</a></button>
    <button id="w1e5" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1e5()"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 5 (EP.005/156)</a></button>
    <button id="w1e6" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1e6()"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 6 (EP.006/156)</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, all onclick functions above have the same code. Is there a simpler code to make it like below?

User clicks whichever button in the dropdown (whether it's just one button, or multiple buttons but of course can't be clicked at the same time), then the button becomes black and its ID stored in sessionStorage, so after the page being refreshed, sessionStorage get the button's ID and keep that button's state which is that button is in black because it has been clicked by the user.

Thank you in advance to everyone who make a time for answering my question.

Comment: yes, use `onclick="fn(this)"` then use the passed in argument as the element to add the style to etc ... then a simple manipulation of the `id` of the object passed in to uppercase it

Comment: `window.onload = function() {` <-- **Don't do this**

Answer (score 0):

Check the changes,i made also a single function to handle your conditional styling.

i did'nt quite understand what are you trying to do with the first part of the code where you iterate `document.getElementsByClassName("week_dropdown-button")`,care to explain ?

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("week_dropdown-button");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}


function w1(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById(id).style.border = "solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
  sessionStorage.setItem(id, id);
}


window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".week_content-button .button").forEach(el => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem(el.id)) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      el.style.border = "solid 1px rgb(75,75,75)";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.week_dropdown-button{
  padding: 0.2em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px outset darkgrey;
  background-color: rgb(75,75,75);
  width: 11.1em;
}
.week_dropdown-button:hover{
  background: darkgrey;
  border: inset rgb(75,75,75);
}
.button:hover{
  background: darkgrey;
}
.week_dropdown-container{
  height: max-content;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 12.5em;
}
.week_content-button{
  background: rgb(75,75,75);
  
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%; /* lebarnya terhadap week_dropdown-container */
  text-align: center;
}
.button{
  background-color: rgb(75,75,75);
  border: solid 1px black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 0;
}
a, a:hover, a:visited{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.active{
  background: darkgrey;
  color: black;
  border: inset rgb(75,75,75);
}
```

```html
<button class="week_dropdown-button">WEEK 1</button>
<div class="week_dropdown-container">
    <div class="week_content-button">
        <button id="w1e1" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1(this.id)"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 1 (EP.001/156)</a></button>
        <button id="w1e2" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1(this.id)"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 2 (EP.002/156)</a></button>
        <button id="w1e3" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1(this.id)"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 3 (EP.003/156)</a></button>
        <button id="w1e4" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1(this.id)"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 4 (EP.004/156)</a></button>
        <button id="w1e5" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1(this.id)"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 5 (EP.005/156)</a></button>
        <button id="w1e6" class="button" type="button" onclick="w1(this.id)"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="external">Episode 6 (EP.006/156)</a></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, that code is for showing the contents in the dropdown button when user clicks that button & also hiding the contents when user clicks that button again.